# fiftyone states "Not Found" instead of showing GUI

Tags: python, fiftyone

I hope someone can help.

tyring to simply show the fiftyone GUI in Windows11. I always just says "Not Found".

Tried
Different Anaconda environments (Python 3.10 and 3.9)
Using jupyter notbook version
Using Python 3.10 without anaconda

Here is an exmaple

[image: running session = fo.launch_app(dataset) just shows not found]

I'm new to fiftyone, but following the tutorials, should be simple.
Tried: https://docs.voxel51.com/getting_started/install.html
Example and Tried: https://docs.voxel51.com/tutorials/evaluate_detections.html

All give a "Not Found" message, and no web interface. (when using browser, it's a 404, but with "Not Found" text returned, very odd)

my environment

```
    System Information:
- OS: Windows
- OS Version: 10.0.22621
- Architecture: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
- Python Version: 3.10.12 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jul  5 2023, 19:01:18) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it would seem in windows, it just dosn't work as a web app for whatever reason.

But does work as a desktop app, yay. if you fix a registry setting.

Note to self and any othe poor soul that happens accross this.

In Anaconda, open up the IPython console

Paste in the below as a quickstart

```
import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz

dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset("quickstart")
session = fo.launch_app(dataset, desktop=1)
```

Then wait a while, it will load up.
Notice desktop=1

If it dosn't work, open registry editor, naviagate to
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.js
Create a new string key
Content Type Value=application/javascript

restart computer, and try again.